# Call a Python method by name

Tags: python

If I have an object and a method name in a string, how can I call the method?

```
class Foo:
    def bar1(self):
        print 1
    def bar2(self):
        print 2

def callMethod(o, name):
    ???

f = Foo()
callMethod(f, "bar1")
```

Comment: Very closely related (heck, maybe even dupe): [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](//stackoverflow.com/q/2612610). Methods are attributes, too.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the built-in [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
class Foo:
    def bar1(self):
        print(1)
    def bar2(self):
        print(2)

def call_method(o, name):
    return getattr(o, name)()


f = Foo()
call_method(f, "bar1")  # prints 1
```

You can also use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) for setting class attributes by names.

Comment: I could not find what to search in the documentation! Thanks!

Comment: @Jazz, it's under builtins. You might have to do an in-page search with `C-f`

Comment: @aaronasterling I know, but I could not find what word to search!

Comment: why callMethod(f, "bar1") is not called f.callMethod(f, "bar1")

Comment: PhilipJ, because it's just a method defined a couple of line earlier, outside Foo: class.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `getattr` rather than `f.__getattribute__` ?

Answer (score 11):

I had similar question, wanted to call instance method by reference. Here are funny things I found:

```
instance_of_foo=Foo()

method_ref=getattr(Foo, 'bar')
method_ref(instance_of_foo) # instance_of_foo becomes self

instance_method_ref=getattr(instance_of_foo, 'bar')
instance_method_ref() # instance_of_foo already bound into reference
```

Python is amazing!

Answer (score 3):

```
getattr(globals()['Foo'](), 'bar1')()
getattr(globals()['Foo'](), 'bar2')()
```

No need to instantiate Foo first!

Comment: It was only an example, I have real instance of a real class!

Comment: Calling a Method of a uninitialized class maybe implies you're doing something wrong.

Comment: what if `foo` isn't in globals?

Comment: it probably isn't, but you should take care that `Foo` is. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
def callmethod(cls, mtd_name):    
    method = getattr(cls, mtd_name)
    method()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generalized version using Python decorators. You can call by short or long name. I found it useful when implementing CLI with short and long sub commands.

Python decorators are wonderful. Bruce Eckel (Thinking in Java) describes Python decorators beautifully here.

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808
http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from functools import wraps


class CommandInfo(object):
    cmds = []

    def __init__(self, shortname, longname, func):
        self.shortname = shortname
        self.longname = longname
        self.func = func


class CommandDispatch(object):
    def __init__(self, shortname, longname):
        self.shortname = shortname
        self.longname = longname

    def __call__(self, func):
        print("hello from CommandDispatch's __call__")

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(wself, *args, **kwargs):
            print('hello from wrapped_func, args:{0}, kwargs: {1}'.format(args, kwargs))
            func(wself, *args, **kwargs)

        ci = CommandInfo
        ci.cmds += [ci(shortname=self.shortname, longname=self.longname, func=func)]
        return wrapped_func

    @staticmethod
    def func(name):
        print('hello from CommandDispatch.func')

        for ci in CommandInfo.cmds:
            if ci.shortname == name or ci.longname == name:
                return ci.func

        raise RuntimeError('unknown command')


@CommandDispatch(shortname='co', longname='commit')
def commit(msg):
    print('commit msg: {}'.format(msg))


commit('sample commit msg')         # Normal call by function name

cd = CommandDispatch
short_f = cd.func(name='co')        # Call by shortname
short_f('short sample commit msg')

long_f = cd.func(name='commit')     # Call by longname
long_f('long sample commit msg')


class A(object):
    @CommandDispatch(shortname='Aa', longname='classAmethoda')
    def a(self, msg):
        print('A.a called, msg: {}'.format(msg))


a = A()
short_fA = cd.func(name='Aa')
short_fA(a, 'short A.a msg')

long_fA = cd.func(name='classAmethoda')
long_fA(a, 'short A.a msg')
```