# Python: call a method with the name stored in a variable

Tags: python

I am writing a python program where in I have included another python file.

The python file included has a method which I want to invoke from the calling script.

Like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
include script1

method = sys.argv[1]     # values may be - create or destroy

if method == "create":
    script1.create()
elif method == "destroy":
    script1.destroy()
```

Now, what I want is,

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
include script1

method = sys.argv[1]       # values may be - create or destroy

script1.method()
```

and, it should use the **value** inside the variable **method** instead of trying to call the module called `method`.

Comment: `if method = create` ?? at least post valid code

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it was only supposed to be pseudo for understanding... but anyways, ill correct it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Python method by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521715/call-a-python-method-by-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
method= sys.argv[1]
getattr(script1, method)()
```

Answer (score 0):

To call functions from `script1`, you could turn it into a module.

script1.py:

```
def create():
   pass

def destroy():
   pass
```

script2.py:

```
import script1

script1.create()
script1.destroy()
```