# How to turn the ".get" in Python requests.get into a variable?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to programming with Python. I'd like to set a variable for the Python `requests` method (`.get`, `.post`, etc.).

**Something like:**

```
import requests

method = 'get'
url = 'https://google.com'

response = requests.method(url)
```

This of course results in an error because `requests` does not have a `.method` option.

It feels like the answer lies with `getattr`, but I don't understand what parameters to pass `getattr`.

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: That's a job better suited for [`requests.request`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request).

Comment: That is very handy. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```py
import requests

get = requests.get
post = requests.post
put = requests.put
patch = requests.patch
delete = requests.delete

url = 'https://google.com'

google = get(url)
```

If you would like it as a class you can use the following code:

```py
import requests


class Methods:
    def __init__(self):
        self.get = requests.get
        self.post = requests.post
        self.put = requests.put
        self.patch = requests.patch
        self.delete = requests.delete


methods = Methods()
url = 'https://google.com'
method = "get"

google = getattr(methods, method)(url)
```

Comment: That is valuable, and does work thank you. Though I would like to know how/if its possible to make the dot notation options into variables.

Comment: Check if this gives some more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521715/call-a-python-method-by-name

Comment: @SeaDude Added that as well

Comment: This does nothing to address the actual question.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal The OP is asking for a way to execute arbitrary methods that are string variables.

Comment: @Selcuk  Please check the answer again

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal What I mean is your method won't work if I want to execute `"foobar"` method. Why are you even declaring a `Methods` class? Can't you directly `getattr` from `requests`?

Comment: @Selcuk If any other variable is defined in the `Methods` class (not from `requests`) then it can be directly accessed.