# Call method by annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the code below

```
class Test:
  def method(self, name):
    if name == 'a':
      return __method_a()
    if name == 'b':
      return __method_b()

  def __method_a(self):
    print('a')

  def __method_b(self):
    print('b')
  ...
```

Is there a way to do something "nicer", for example by using annotations?

```
class Test:
  def method(self, name: str):
    return self.call_by_annot(name)

  @a
  def __method_a(self):
    print('a')

  @b
  def __method_b(self):
    print('b')
  ...
```

If not, which is an excellent way to remove such a list of `if`?

Comment: Does [Call a Python method by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521715/call-a-python-method-by-name) answer your question?

Comment: .. [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: Maybe combine `getattr`  with a class attribute mapping letters to method names (e.g.`{'a':'__method_a',...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
class Test:

    def method(self,name):
        return getattr(self,f"__method_{name}")()

    def __method_a():...
    def __method_b():...
```

Comment: for private methods it should be `getattr(self,f"_Test__method_{name}")()`